# Why id changed on "undefined" after submit in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, submit

I have the folowing method in component:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    const successCallback = (result) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        if (result) {
            this.notificationId = result.Id;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['../' + this.notificationId], { relativeTo: this.route });
    };

    if (this.isNew) {
        this.dataService.create(this.model).then(successCallback);
    } else {
        this.dataService.update(this.model).then(successCallback);
    }
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.notificationId = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params['notificationid'], 10);
    this.projectId = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params['projectid'], 10);
    let loadTask: Promise<NotificationOfParticipationViewModel>;

    if (this.notificationId == 0) {
        loadTask = Promise.resolve(new NotificationOfParticipationViewModel());
    } else {
        loadTask = this.dataService.getById(this.notificationId);
    }

    loadTask.then(result => {
        this.model = Object.assign(new NotificationOfParticipationViewModel(), result);
        this.isLoading = false;
    });
}
```

in service:

```
update(notification: NotificationOfParticipationViewModel): Promise<any> {
    return this.baseService.put(this.apiUrl, notification);
}

create(signatory: NotificationOfParticipationViewModel): Promise<NotificationOfParticipationViewModel> {
    return this.baseService.post(this.apiUrl, signatory);
}
```

Server does some calculations after submit.

Before submit URL look like:

```
http://localhost:55077/projects/2/notificationsofparticipation/26
```

But after submit URL look like:

```
http://localhost:55077/projects/2/notificationsofparticipation/undefined
```

I don't understand, why `26` changed on `undefined`?

Comment: have you initialized `notificationId ` in the component class elsewhere ? if no, make sure that `result ` has property `id` otherwise in the next line of the if statement  `notificationId ` will be undefined.

Comment: Can you post a server code?

Answer (score 1):

```
        onSubmit() {
            this.isLoading = true;
            const successCallback = (result) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
                if (result && result.hasOwnProperty("Id")) {
                    this.notificationId = result.Id;
                }else{
                   console.log("ID not present in result obj");
                }
                this.router.navigate(['../' + this.notificationId], { relativeTo: this.route });
            };

            if (this.isNew) {
                this.dataService.create(this.model).then(successCallback);
            } else {
                this.dataService.update(this.model).then(successCallback);
            }
        }
```